# How to submit job on Dataproc cluster with specific service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc, service-accounts

I'm trying to execute jobs in the Dataproc cluster which access several resources of GCP like Google Cloud Storage.

My concern is whatever file or object is being created through my job is owned/created by Dataproc default user.

Example - `123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

Is there any way I can configure this user/service-account so that the object gets created by a given user/service-account instead of default one?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure service account to be used by a Dataproc cluster using flag `--service-account` at cluster creation time.

Gcloud command would look like:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name \
  --service-account=your-service-account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

More details: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/iam/iam

Note: it is better to have one dataproc cluster per job so that each job get isolated environment and doesnt affect each other and you can manage them better (in terms of security as well).

you can also look at GCP Composer using which you can schedule jobs and automate them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a use case where I need to run various jobs on a single dataproc cluster using different service accounts. 
Each service account has different IAM policies. I want to leverage these IAM policies when submitting the jobs.

Can we also submit multiple jobs at a time? on a single cluster with different service accounts.

Comment: I doubt you can attach and remove IAM policies to a cluster in GCP yet.

Comment: I'd say this is something you don't want to do as a security practice. To use different service accounts per-job you'd have to provide service account keys, and those would have to be stored either in GCS (and be accessible to the cluster SA) or worse on the cluster itself. If you want to use narrowly tailored permissions, I would suggest creating per-job clusters via workflow templates

Comment: What's the reason for using same dataproc cluster for multiple jobs? Ideally, you should have dataproc cluster come up then run a job and tear down.

Comment: @tix , I understand this is not secure, but we have a weird requirement, for which we tried making the keys of a service account with no access to google storage available on the cluster itself. After this, we were not able to access the storage account when running the jobs by ssh-ing into the cluster. But when I try it by submitting it as a job via gcloud, the job is able to access the storage account. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand the bit about submitting jobs vs ssh-ing. Both should work the same. Either way, GCS and BQ connectors expose [properties](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/fs/gcs/GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.java#L110) for configuring auth from key file -- this is insecure, please don't do it!